# saving the state of listbox containing checkbox for wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I created a button to create multiple checkbox on no. of clicks for wp7. Below the codes I used for it.

```xml
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
 <TextBox x:Name="txtNewTask" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="72" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="328"/>
 <Button x:Name="btnAdd" Content="add" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="328,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="123" Click="btnAdd_Click"/>
 <ListBox x:Name="lbToDoList" Margin="0,72,0,0">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
       <CheckBox Click="CheckBox_Click" Background="{x:Null}">
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Name="tbkTextName" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,5,0" />
         </StackPanel>
       </CheckBox>
     </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Now when I exit and re-open my app, the checkboxes are unchecked (default state) and their state is not saved. And if I use `x:Name` for that checkbox, then I could save the state but since all the checkboxes are assigned to same name, therefore all checkboxes state becomes the same.

**When App is active**

[image: When App is active]

**When App is reactivated**

[image: When App is reactivated]

Can anybody please help me to save the checkbox's state that is inside a listbox?

Comment: It's called "saving state". There are multiple ways of making it happen. Here is one example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967548(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: @Eugene Is there any other way to do it, because the above example is not working for me!

Comment: As I mentioned before, there are plenty other ways of doing it. If you google "win phone save state", hopefully you will find something that would work for you. There is no "umbrella" solution, it depends on what you use in your solution.

Answer (score 0):

This should do:

XAML:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtNewTask" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="72" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="328"/>
<Button x:Name="btnAdd" Content="add" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="328,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="123" Click="btnAdd_Click"/>
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" x:Name="lbToDoList" Margin="0,72,0,0">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked,Mode=TwoWay}" Background="{x:Null}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Name="tbkTextName" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,5,0" />
                </StackPanel>
            </CheckBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainPage:PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        lbToDoList.ItemsSource = IsolatedStorageHelper.Instance.Tasks;
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
        IsolatedStorageHelper.Instance.Save();
    }

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsolatedStorageHelper.Instance.Tasks.Add(new MyTask()
        {
            Name = txtNewTask.Text
        });
    }
}

public class IsolatedStorageHelper
{
    public static IsolatedStorageHelper Instance = new IsolatedStorageHelper();
    private IsolatedStorageSettings Settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
    public ObservableCollection<MyTask> _tasks;
    public ObservableCollection<MyTask> Tasks
    {
        get
        {
            if (_tasks == null)
            {
                if (!Settings.Contains("Tasks"))
                    Settings["Tasks"] = new List<MyTask>();
                _tasks = new ObservableCollection<MyTask>((List<MyTask>)Settings["Tasks"]);
                _tasks.CollectionChanged += _tasks_CollectionChanged;
            }
            return _tasks;
        }
    }

    void _tasks_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Save();
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        Settings["Tasks"] = _tasks.ToList();
    }
}
public class MyTask
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```